# Why does the Vilna Gaon feature so prominently in the discourse of the Ashkenazi Yeshiva world?

Tags: yeshiva-school, vilna-gaon

Why does the Vilna Gaon appear to be emphasized in the Ashkenazi Yeshiva world to a greater extent than other contemporaries of his such as Rav Yonathan Eybeschütz?

Comment: His talmid, Reb Chaim Volozhiner, was the founder of the Ashkenazi yeshiva system in use today. He is referred to by many as "The Father of the Yeshivos". The Gr"a being his Rebbe would by extension be held in high esteem.

Comment: Vote to close as Primarily Opinion Based.

Comment: @DoubleAA The question is phrased disrespectfully, as well as being opinion based.

Comment: I suppose the comparison itself is offensive https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Eybeschutz#Sabbatian_controversy

Comment: @Kazi despite the controversy, Rav Eybeschutz is held in his esteem, his seforim featuring prominently everywhere Torah is learned

Comment: @robev That's perfectly fine, but how can you compare him to the Gr"a who was a prolific author **and** a role model through his piety and personal integrity. (I might be biased due to R' Emden, but still.)

Comment: Rav Yonathan Eibeshüts was very prolific, urim vetumim kreti ufleti ect, perhaps not less than the gaon

Comment: @Kazibácsi Ask some chasidim if the gaon was a part of any significant controversies...

Comment: @Double AA, I was thinking the same thing... though I do wonder (and it may be too much of a tangent for this thread) but do any Hasidic sources directly condemn the persona of the GR"A? It is my impression that their approach is that he was very mistaken on the particular issue of Hasidism but that his integrity and piety are unquestionable.

Comment: Usually these things go by how people were viewed by their contemporaries and the next generation. It is hard for later generations to recreate the dynamics that led to the original assessment. For example, my respect for certain seforim went up when I saw how much my Rebbeim respected them.

Answer (score 2):

A dominant trend in Ashkenaz during the GR"A's period was to treat the Shulhan Arukh as a primary source for issuing halakhic rulings. The GR"A sought to revive the practice of sourcing halakhah directly from the Talmud (dina deGemara).

R. Yonathan Eibishitz on the other hand took the Shulhan Arukh/Rema to be written with ruah ha-qodesh and therefore then an appropriate source from which to directly issue halakhic rulings.

The GR"A's approach may not seem all that revolutionary from a contemporary perspective. However this is likely due to the fact that he succeeded largely in moving the needle. Contemporary Ashkenazi poseqim today largely take a moderated approach between the two extremes and try to issue rulings that are simultaneously deferential to precedent and rooted in dina deGemara.

So in summary, one of the reasons that "the Vilna Gaon features so prominently in the discourse of the Ashkenazi Yeshiva world" is because he was extremely influential in shaping halakhic methodology as contemporaneously practiced.

If you'd like to read more about this topic, I recommend Rabbi Moshe Walter's book "The Making of a Halachic Decision."

Answer (score 0):

I definitely think it depends on the community, I've lived all over the US and it varies when I lived in Passaic it was all about the Vilna Gaon. Other places I've lived, especially if the community rabbi is a 50ish year old graduate of YU they'll constantly cite Rav Soloveichik.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!